# Setting default font size for graphs in Powerpoint

Tags: templates, ms-office, powerpoint

I've found no other stackexchange site to ask this question so I present it here. If there's a more appropriate place for it please let me know.

I have just been given a ms-powerpoint template document to fix. It was created by designers using the slide master editor in MS-Office 2011 for Mac. The problem is that when the customer creates a new slide using one of these templates and then wants to insert a chart into one of the designated boxes (which is only one of the things that can be stuck in there) the text in the chart is always set at 18pt. I've looked everywhere for a setting that sets the default font size for charts (and smart art) for **only that document** but have been unable to find it.

Any pointers or help of any kind would be more than great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the following answer from James Gordon from a Microsoft forum:

> Charts are handled by Excel. In Excel you can create Chart Template,
>   which are saved in (.crtx) file format and will appear in the Ribbon.
>   The way to do it is to customize a chart and then right-click on the
>   chart. Use the Save As Template option from the pop-up menu. If you
>   save your template in the Chart Templates folder (the default when the
>   save dialog opens), after you quit and then re-open Excel, the
>   template will be available to you in the Ribbon.
>
> SmartArt is within your PowerPoint presentation. There are various
>   approaches you might take regarding SmartArt. As you pointed out,
>   SmartArt can be specified in a Slide Master, or on Slide Design.
>   Saving a presentation as a Theme (.thmx) is one option. Another save
>   option is to save as a Template, which is more comprehensive (includes
>   every aspect of a slide show).